# Regex PCRE - Removing ONLY certain characters from a String

Tags: regex, pcre

The PCRE Regex I tried finds the first character and deletes everything else after it.

**Here are the String samples:**

```
$128.48 One Month TV Internet and Voice, 100GB of Fiber<sup>&dagger;</sup> Internet.

$148.48 One Month TV Internet and Voice, 200GB of Fiber<sup>&dagger;</sup> Internet and a free movie rental from MoviePlex.
```

I want to extract ONLY the following characters from the String and keep the rest of the String as is. Extract: `<sup>&dagger  </sup>`

**Expected Result**:

```
$148.48 One Month TV Internet and Voice, 200GB of Fiber;Internet and a free movie rental from MoviePlex.

$128.48 One Month TV Internet and Voice, 100GB of Fiber; Internet.
```

Here is the Regex that I tried:

```
[^&dagger<sup><\/sup>]*
```

Comment: And by "Extract" you mean remove? If the `<sup>&dagger;</sup>` is static you don't need regex - just replace it with an empty string.

Comment: Yes, 'Remove' ...I just need the Regex syntax...Since I am inserting the Regex into a tool. I am not writing actual code/script.

Comment: So the regex could simply be `<sup>&dagger;</sup>`. Depending on the tools flavor, you may need to escape the `/`, i.e. `<sup>&dagger;<\/sup>`. Check [this example](https://regex101.com/r/mqN7vb/1).

Comment: The above comment Results with Match 1 being: <sup>&dagger;</sup> Match 1 Result should be "$128.48 One Month TV Internet and Voice, 100GB of Fiber; Internet."

Comment: You should **replace**, like the example I provided. You can't have regex match separate parts of a string, without matching anything in between. I.e. in `AAABBBCCC` you can't match `AAA` and `CCC` w/o matching BBB. You can **capture** `AAA` and `CCC` separately, but they'll end up in separate capture groups. Another way, using replace, would be to replace the whole string, in what case you could try a capture the first and the last part with `(.*)<sup>&dagger;<\/sup>(.*)|(.*)`, replacing with `$1$2$3` (or `\1\2\3` depending on your tool). [See regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/mqN7vb/2).

Answer (score 0):

[That's how you could do this in Perl](https://ideone.com/N2F87j):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use Data::Dumper;

my @strings = (
    '$128.48 One Month TV Internet and Voice, 100GB of Fiber<sup>&dagger;</sup> Internet.',
    '$148.48 One Month TV Internet and Voice, 200GB of Fiber<sup>&dagger;</sup> Internet and a free movie rental from MoviePlex.'
);

my @updated_strings = map { my $str = $_; $str =~ s/<sup>.+?<\/sup>/;/; $str; } @strings;

print 'UPDATED: ' . Dumper(\@updated_strings) . "\n";
```

Also you can play with this in language-agnostic regex101.com: [example](https://regex101.com/r/hSmsfC/1/)